# Can't persist checkstate in reactjs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This would be my first time of doing this and I can't seem to find a way around it. I would like to persist check box state in react.js and would like this to be done without my MongoDB database. Here are my codes so far:
I am fetching list of subscribers from my MongoDB database like this:

```
   const [allSubscribers, setAllSubscribers] = useState([]);

const response = await axiosPrivate.get(`${BASE_URL}/emailsub/subscribers?page=${pageNumber})
 setAllSubscribers(response.data)
```

This displays 9 subscribers per page. On next page, a new API call is made and another 9 subscribers listed, until the last set of items. That is how I handled the pagination via query.

To create the input checkbox, I had to create another array based on the size of the subscribers fetched from the database.

```
 const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState();
 const totalPosts = allSubscribers.length // to get the length of the items fetched from database
 const fillArray = new Array(totalPosts).fill( false)//created new array and fill it with initial value of `false`

//useEffecct to set the check state whenever the all subscriber state changes
useEffect(()=>{
setCheckedState(fillArray)
}, [allSubscribers])
```

When the checkbox is clicked it returns the opposite of the value of the matched item. And the subscriber Id is passed into an array which is a state called   `const [selectedSubscriberId, setSelectedSubscriberId] = useState([]);`

```
 const arrayOfSelectedPostId = (subscriberId, indexPosition) =>{

   setSelectedSubscriberId(prevArray => [...prevArray, subscriberId]);
   const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index == indexPosition ? !item : item
   )
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
 }
```

When unchecked, I removed the matched subscriberId from the `selectedSubscriberId` array.

```
   //handle deselecting of a selected postid
    const handleChangeState = (subscriberId)=>{
     selectedSubscriberId.map((item)=>{
       console.log(item === subscriberId)
       if(item === subscriberId){
           const newArray = selectedSubscriberId.filter((item) => item !==subscriberId)
         
         
           setSelectedSubscriberId(newArray);
           
       }
   })
   };
```

This is the checkbox input:

```
 <input type="checkbox"  id={index} checked={checkedState[index]} onChange={()=>{arrayOfSelectedPostId(subscriberId, index); handleChangeState(subscriberId)}}/>
```

On page load or refresh, I want to check the `selectedSubscriberId` array and any subscriber id found there should remain checked. Is there a way I can handle this? I don't mind reworking the code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you overcomplicated your state a bit. You could achieve checkboxes state handling using 1 array that holds only ids (for example) of checked items. And 2 utility functions, 1 to check if item is checked and 1 to actually add or remove items from this array of ids.

Next - you would need 2 useEffects. One useEffect will load checked ids array from localstorage on first component render, and 2nd one will update localstorage when array of ids is updated.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const DATA = [
  { id: 1, name: "sub1" },
  { id: 2, name: "sub2" },
  { id: 3, name: "sub3" },
  { id: 4, name: "sub4" },
  { id: 5, name: "sub5" }
];

const CHECKED_SUBSCRIBERS_IDS_KEY = "checked_subscribers_ids";
const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 2;

export default function App() {
  const [allSubscribers, setAllSubscribers] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  // initial state for it is "undefined"!
  const [checkedSubscribersIds, setCheckedSubscribersIds] = useState();

  // initial load of checked items from localstorage
  useEffect(() => {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(CHECKED_SUBSCRIBERS_IDS_KEY);
    setCheckedSubscribersIds(json ? JSON.parse(json) : []);
  }, []);

  // update localstorage on checked items changed.
  useEffect(() => {
    // initial load needs to be ignored
    if (!checkedSubscribersIds) return;
    const json = JSON.stringify(checkedSubscribersIds);
    localStorage.setItem(CHECKED_SUBSCRIBERS_IDS_KEY, json);
  }, [checkedSubscribersIds]);

  // dummy data set and pagination, ignore
  useEffect(() => {
    const items = [...DATA].slice(
      page * ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
      page * ITEMS_PER_PAGE + ITEMS_PER_PAGE
    );
    setAllSubscribers(items);
  }, [page]);
  
  const isChecked = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      if (!checkedSubscribersIds) return false;
      return checkedSubscribersIds.includes(item.id);
    },
    [checkedSubscribersIds]
  );

  const handleCheckedClick = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      const idx = checkedSubscribersIds.findIndex((x) => x === item.id);
      if (idx >= 0) {
        checkedSubscribersIds.splice(idx, 1);
      } else {
        checkedSubscribersIds.push(item.id);
      }
      setCheckedSubscribersIds([...checkedSubscribersIds]);
    },
    [checkedSubscribersIds]
  );

  // ignore
  const onPrevPageClick = () => {
    setPage(page <= 0 ? 0 : page - 1);
  };
  // ignore
  const onNextPageClick = () => {
    setPage(page + 1 >= DATA.length / ITEMS_PER_PAGE ? page : page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Checked</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {allSubscribers.map((x) => (
            <tr key={x.id}>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={isChecked(x)}
                  onChange={() => handleCheckedClick(x)}
                />
              </td>
              <td>{x.id}</td>
              <td>{x.name}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" onClick={onPrevPageClick}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={onNextPageClick}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So basically with my code you added an array that stores ids of items that are "checked". This array is called `checkedSubscribersIds`. Next it comes to the `handleCheckedClick` function declaration, i wrapped it in useCallback just because I used to do that for any function, in your case it is not really needed but still it will be better if you will be aware of `useCallback` and you should read the react docs about it. It is about performance basically. There is a place to improve it anyway but I dont want to overcomplicate my answer. And the idea is pretty simple, you click on checkbox - `handleCheckedClick` function is called with `item` (x) parameter, inside of it you are checking if the `id` exists in the `checkedSubscribersIds` and if it does exist - you are removing it from this array. If not - adding. And the final is the `setCheckedSubscribersIds([...checkedSubscribersIds]);` which is cloning the array and setting the new reference which is the only way to make react understand that the array changed and we need a rerender. Doing so - 2 things are happening. 1) rerender is called which reevaluates the expression inside of `<input>` - `checked={isChecked(x)}`. 2) `useEffect` is triggered due to it has `[checkedSubscribersIds]` as a dependency array, which will serialize this array to json and store it in localStorage.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, if I may ask, what is the DATA variable for?

Comment: from the look of thing, my own pagination system is quite different from yours. I have been sensing that could be the issue for me too. For instance, I load data 9 item per page. I think you are using slice to render the data, right? This means all data would be fetched at once and rendered per slice number judging from your codes? In my own case, per page, a new API call is made. Will this affect your code?

Comment: Well, your solution would work for a data that is static from the database. If you check my question properly, you would know that I stated that allSubscribers were coming from mongoDB and that it changes per page and 9 items are listed per page until the last set of items. What this means is that the allSubscribers is not static and can change. I can not possible fetch all the data at once. What if the data coming is over 500 items? Your pagination was done using a system that fetches all data at once and uses slice to render it per page. Mine calls the API on each new page

Comment: I have been able to resolve my issue using part of ur codes. I ddint use to localstorage system or useEffect. My entire code is a bit complicated. I mean the real because I am working on dashboard system. I wanted the checkState to persist per page loaded from my API call and part of your code has solved that. Thank you very much. But I would like to understand the logics behind the handleCheckedClick function. I wish to understand how exactly the logic works.

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz Sure, I updated my answer with some details. If you have any other questions - ask, please

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I have read the updated answer. It is clearer now what the function is doing. I guess I was a little bit confused with the if statement of the selectedId index when >= 0. Thanks once again.